# I have few labels and a datagridview on the form I want to print data from these controls in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have few labels and a datagrid control on the form, I want to print data from these controls in c#

```
    private void CaptureScreen()
    {
        Graphics myGraphics = printPanel.CreateGraphics();
        Size s = printPanel.Size;
        memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
        Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
        Point screenLoc = PointToScreen(printPanel.Location); // Get the location of the Panel in Screen Coordinates
        memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(screenLoc.X, screenLoc.Y, 0, 0, s);
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(System.Object sender,
           System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Client Side**

```
<asp:Button ID="printButton" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick="javascript:window.print();" />
```

**Server Side**

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"PrintOperation","printing()",true);
```

**javascript**

```
function printing()
        {
            window.print();


        }
```